# Second-level property binding in wpf Datagrid DataGridTemplateColumn TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, binding, datagrid

I have got a dataGrid with columns created with the help of DataGridTemplateColumn technology. 
Here is the column I am interested in in my DataGrid (Name = "Dgrv)

---

### XAML

---

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="40">
                    <!--="Name"-->
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextCell.txtbx}" 
                                           TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0, 8, 0, 0"/>
                                <Canvas Background="Black" Height="1" Margin="5,5,5,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding OperatorCode}" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0, 5, 0, 0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

In my backend I have got the next code:

---

### XAML.cs

---

```
var list = new List<Contract>();
        list.Add(new Contract
        {
            ID = 1,
            CompanyName = "Технабсервис",
            HeadName = "Петров\nАлександр\nНиколаевич",
            CountryCode = "+7",
            OperatorCode = "495",
            Date = Convert.ToDateTime("21.02.2012").ToString("dd.MM"), //GetDateTimeFormats('mm, dd'), 
            Time = "16:39",
            Telephones = "(495)123-4567 (общий)",
            Comment = ""
        });
Dgrv.ItemsSource = list;
```

---

### Here is my class Contract.cs

---

```
public class Contract
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string HeadName { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        public string OperatorCode { get; set; }
        public String Date { get; set; }
        public String Time { get; set; }
        public String Telephones { get; set; }
        public String Comment { get; set; }
        public TextCell smth { get; set; }

        /*public Dictionary<string, int> PriceFields { get; private set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> RateFields { get; private set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> TypeFields { get; private set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> TicketFields { get; private set; }*/

        public Contract()
        {
            smth = new TextCell();
        }
    }
```

And, finally my class TextCell (as you could see, I want to bind TextBlock`s text to the field of this class with name "txtbx"

---

### TextCell.cs

---

```
public class TextCell
    {
        public String txtbx { get; set; }
        public TextCell()
        {
            txtbx = "sdbjshfk";
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return txtbx;
        }
    }
```

So, the question is about this part of code

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TextCell.txtbx}" 
                                               TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0, 8, 0, 0"/>
```

It is not working at all. I understand, that I can bind TextBlock`s text to the TextCell field itself. The ToString() method will be called in such case, but that is not enough for me. Mainly, because the situation described in this post is just an example and I have got far more situations where I will need such type of binding.

So, the TextCell class has been created just as an example in order to understand the required technology.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{Binding smth.txtbx}`?

Comment: I do not understand, how it is possible, but it works. I have tried your variant several times, but that did not work. After your comment I decided to try another time and it worked. Thanks a lot. Could you tell me, please, how to mark the answer as the correct one?

Comment: I posted an answer, trying to explain things the best I can. You should be able to mark that as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple.

If you want to bind to a subproperty you have to use the properties names in the `Binding` markup extension.

When you write `{Binding TextCell.txtbx}`, of course it's not going to work, because you don't have a property called `TextCell` on `Contract`. You have a property of type `TextCell` called `smth`. Similarly from C# code you would try to reach that property using the following code:

```
var list = new List();
list.Add(new Contract
{
    ID = 1,
    CompanyName = "Технабсервис",
    HeadName = "Петров\nАлександр\nНиколаевич",
    CountryCode = "+7",
    OperatorCode = "495",
    Date = Convert.ToDateTime("21.02.2012").ToString("dd.MM"), //GetDateTimeFormats('mm, dd'), 
    Time = "16:39",
    Telephones = "(495)123-4567 (общий)",
    Comment = ""
});

var x = list[0].smth.txtbx;
```

By the way you should be consistent with your naming conventions. You should use [Pascal casing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx) for public properties.

You can read more about the syntax of the `Binding` markup extension [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752300(v=vs.100).aspx#Path_Syntax).

There is still some problem with your code. If you do an update to the fields from code it wouldn't update the UI. In order to make `list[0].smth.txtbx = "Updated Text";` work you should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your `Contract` and `TextCell` classes. Something along these lines:

```
public class Contract : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _id;
    private string _companyName;
    private string _headName;
    private string _countryCode;
    private string _operatorCode;
    private string _date;
    private string _time;
    private string _telephones;
    private string _comment;
    private TextCell _smth;

    public int ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string CompanyName
    {
        get { return _companyName; }
        set
        {
            _companyName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string HeadName
    {
        get { return _headName; }
        set
        {
            _headName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string CountryCode
    {
        get { return _countryCode; }
        set
        {
            _countryCode = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string OperatorCode
    {
        get { return _operatorCode; }
        set
        {
            _operatorCode = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public String Date
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set
        {
            _date = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public String Time
    {
        get { return _time; }
        set
        {
            _time = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public String Telephones
    {
        get { return _telephones; }
        set
        {
            _telephones = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public String Comment
    {
        get { return _comment; }
        set
        {
            _comment = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public TextCell smth
    {
        get { return _smth; }
        set
        {
            _smth = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    /*public Dictionary<string, int> PriceFields { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> RateFields { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> TypeFields { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> TicketFields { get; private set; }*/

    public Contract()
    {
        smth = new TextCell();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And for the `TextCell` class:

```
public class TextCell : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _txtbx;

    public String txtbx
    {
        get { return _txtbx; }
        set
        {
            _txtbx = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public TextCell()
    {
        txtbx = "sdbjshfk";
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return txtbx;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I know this is a lot of boilerplate code, but unfortunately you need this if you want your binding to be notified about changes coming from the viewmodel/model.
There is a very good library called [PropertyChanged for Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) which lets you avoid writing all this boilerplate code for the `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementations. But I'm getting sidetracked.

I hope this was/will be useful.

Comment: My apologies for disappearing, the project got closed, but this answer was still useful, thank you